# automating the tests where application running under citrix xenapp

Tags: automation, automated-tests, citrix, xenapp

I am hardly trying to automate some of the scripts for regression testing in the application, but the challenge am facing over here is, the application running under the ***Citrix XenApp*** so am not able to automate it in a usual way(Selenium & UFT) please anyone help me to find the way to automate the application under citrix :)

Answer (score 0):

With Citrix, like any other image based screen, you can use :

- Insigth Object to locate and interact with images on the screen
- GetTextLocation method to locate text using OCR (optical character recognition)
- Low level recording to click at some screen location, by coordinates
- SendKeys function to input text on the screen